# Does Iron Vigil really allow an extended rest at any time?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, rests

There's a ritual in *Divine Power* called *Iron Vigil*:

> You invoke your dedication to your god and let it wash your fatigue and needs from you. Iron Vigil fulfills your body's need for food and water when you perform it and allows you to remain aware and alert **while taking an extended rest anytime during the ritual's duration**.

What *exactly* does the part in bold mean?

If you feel that it could reasonably be interpreted in multiple ways, then I'd appreciate some insight into the consequences of the possible rulings.

Comment: My two answers are the two ways I've read it. I don't know which one is right. If you've got another one, add it.

Comment: Wonder what that downvote is for...

Comment: For anybody else with concerns similar to Oblivious Sage's, here are the meta questions I was thinking about when I chose to post this question like this: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3141/12011, http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5676/12011

Answer (score 12):

The sentence would mean the same thing if you removed the word 'anytime':

> Iron Vigil fulfills your body's need for food and water when you perform it and allows you **to remain aware and alert while taking an extended rest** (during the ritual's duration).

It doesn't impact the time at which you're allowed to take a rest at all, just how aware you are when taking one.

Comment: This is the correct interpretation. While the ritual is active you remain aware & alert during long rests, rather than being lost in the blissful unconsciousness of sleep. The "anytime" is just there to say that that benefit applies for the entire duration, and that you don't have to take the long rest immediately after the performing the ritual or anything like that.

Comment: @ObliviousSage That's what I figured after a while, but when I initially read it I had the other interpretation, so I thought I'd get a few more eyes on it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Because of the sustenance provided by the ritual, you're able to take an extended rest even when exerting yourself.

The specific text "**while taking an extended rest anytime during the ritual's duration**" overrules the general rule about what actions are allowed during an extended rest.